# TVTK Error in Mayavi (Python)

Tags: python, vtk, mayavi

I'm running a Fedora 17 (x64) machine, and I tried installing Mayavi for python via

```
yum install mayavi
```

which worked fine, except every time I write a code where I call a mayavi module (like mlab) :

```
from enthought.mayavi import mlab
```

it yells with the error

```
********************************************************************************
WARNING: Imported VTK version (5.8) does not match the one used
     to build the TVTK classes (5.6). This may cause problems.
     Please rebuild TVTK.
********************************************************************************
```

I've googled, but I don't know how to rebuild TVTK to match with the version of VTK. I suspect this is causing abnormal behaviour, but I can't be sure. How do you rebuild TVTK?

Comment: have you figured out how to rebuild?  I re-ran ccmake but that didn't work for me.

Comment: No... I haven't really tried. When I asked this question I'd already written some code, and now I'm afraid it'll break if I try to rebuild. So I'll probably try in a few weeks when I don't need the code as much anymore. I'll post back here with results!

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the visualization toolkit (http://www.vtk.org/) on your machine is newer than the one used to build the classes that are packaged in mayavi. You'd need to rebuild/install visualization toolkit 5.6 (http://vtk.org/VTK/resources/software.html) or have you tried Mayavi2 (http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/installation.html) - that is probably more up to date, visualization toolkit is currently version 5.10.

Comment: I did install Mayavi2. I suspect the error is because the version of TVTK used to build the yum package is newer than the one on my machine, so I just need to know how to update the TVTK installation. Ideally through some package manager so it'll keep updating as new versions are released. But even if I have to build it myself that's fine!

Answer (score 1):

As of 4.3.1 do not yet support VTK 6.x. This is being worked on currently on master but is not finished yet.

https://github.com/enthought/mayavi/issues/124

Answer (score 0):

I guess you used yum update but didn't do the trick. You can also check for the version in the repository by doing yum info and looking at the version number it displays.
If that does not satisfies you I'm afraid you will have to "use the source"... 
hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and a simple update of mayavi2 did the trick:

```
pip install mayavi2 -U
```